# trying to import calendars from google calendar using gapi

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to import events from different calendars, and then create invoices from each event.
but each time the events count is different, variable event count each time I try to import.

login with google

```
     function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
    
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("{{ $currentCompany->getSetting('api_key') ? $currentCompany->getSetting('api_key') : '' }}");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  
  let Invoices = [];
  async function execute2() {
      await execute();
      sleep(3000);
      addInvoices(Invoices);
  }
```

prepare the calendars list and loop on them to get events.

```
  

// Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  async function execute() {
      Invoices.length = 0 

    return gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({})
        .then(function(response) {
        // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).

         let data = JSON.parse(response.body);

        for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
             let calendar_id = data.items[i].id;
             getEvents(calendar_id, function() {
                 if(i == data.items.length -1) {
                     console.log(Invoices);
                     //console.count(Invoices);
                     
                                         
                 }
             });
            
         };
         
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
```

get the events for each calendar,
and push it to the invoices array

```
    
   function getEvents(calendar_id, callback) {
      let start_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
      let end_date = new Date($('#end_date').val());
     // console.log(start_date);
     // console.log(end_date);
    return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
         'calendarId': calendar_id,
         'timeMax': end_date.toISOString(),
         'timeMin': start_date.toISOString(),
         'showDeleted': false,
         'singleEvents': true,
         //"alwaysIncludeEmail" : "true",
         //'orderBy': 'updated',
         'maxResults': 2500
     })
        .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            let events =  response.result.items;
            //console.count();
            for(let f = 0; f < events.length; f++) {
                console.count();
                //if(!Invoices.includes(events[f]) )
                //sleep();  
                Invoices.push(events[f]);
                    //console.log(Invoices);
            }
            callback();
            return events;
            //console.count(events);
           },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err);});
  }
    
    
  function sleep(delay) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
      }
```

ajax call to the controller to add the invoices in the DB.

```
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "{{ $currentCompany->getSetting('client_id') ? $currentCompany->getSetting('client_id') : '' }}"});
  });

    function addInvoices(invoices)
    {
        let CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('ajax.ImportInvoicesArr', ['company_uid' => $currentCompany->uid]) }}",
            type: "post",
            delay: 600,
            setTimeout: 5000,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                invoices: JSON.stringify(invoices)
            },
            success: (data) => {
                if(data.status=="success"){
                    window.location.replace("{{ route('invoices', ['company_uid' => $currentCompany->uid]) }}");
                }
                if(data.status=="warning"){
                    window.location.replace("{{ route('invoices.import', ['company_uid' => $currentCompany->uid]) }}");
                }
                if(data.status=="error"){
                    window.location.replace("{{ route('settings.google_api', ['company_uid' => $currentCompany->uid]) }}");
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

the output of the code

```
array:81 [
  0 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4031
    +id: "66m8kfpsjuh4mfk2j6d2c80e81_20210924T110000Z"
    +client_name: "basch karine"
    +created: "2021-04-20T08:43:08.000Z"
    +quantity: 4
    +organizer: "Pirenses"
  }
  1 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4042
    +id: "4bjbfk22pr4kjnmf3t143sr6is_20210917T070000Z"
    +client_name: "tshipamba michel"
    +created: "2021-05-12T08:40:34.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "Pirenses"
  }
  2 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4044
    +id: "76qqv6f4o0eip3clq05l3cg9hr"
    +client_name: "koroglanoglou elena"
    +created: "2021-09-09T15:17:26.000Z"
    +quantity: 4
    +organizer: "Pirenses"
  }
  6 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4032
    +id: "c9h36c1pcphm8bb3cor66b9k6koj8b9pc4q30b9l70o36db56ph30ohp6c_20210917T063000Z"
    +client_name: "neumann laurent"
    +created: "2021-02-04T13:07:35.000Z"
    +quantity: 4.5
    +organizer: "MARJORIE"
  }
  9 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4080
    +id: "b8s541vn356phppr112nv68emm_20210930T063000Z"
    +client_name: "schmit jean"
    +created: "2021-04-09T08:48:26.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  10 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4039
    +id: "751n5a1stgtnvtd5a5k7236jlq_20210927T060000Z"
    +client_name: "lambert sylvie"
    +created: "2020-04-28T09:33:09.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  12 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4093
    +id: "lfqh9qugkugc294mbh45jrfma2_20210928T101500Z"
    +client_name: "hauffels jackie"
    +created: "2020-03-23T09:53:02.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  13 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4097
    +id: "6oqm6or16th3ib9k6cqmab9kcoo3ibb26oq34bb46gq68p1mc8p32cj66o_20210929T110000Z"
    +client_name: "mannes anne"
    +created: "2021-05-04T15:55:01.000Z"
    +quantity: 9
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  14 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4072
    +id: "2blo6d3r2tbmrlgkk6305182np_20210924T063000Z"
    +client_name: "marshall jennifer"
    +created: "2020-07-08T10:47:06.000Z"
    +quantity: 9.0
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  16 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4064
    +id: "1npeu8n28shr4tu8stnfiq1o43_20210930T103000Z"
    +client_name: "jacob stephanie"
    +created: "2020-03-27T08:41:49.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  17 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4101
    +id: "q403fpr9tqp295knfvtp6oq2gl_20210923T060000Z"
    +client_name: "ernzer tania"
    +created: "2020-05-15T08:46:12.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  18 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4114
    +id: "13kchmofvs6uqfu3fvn3l20j9s"
    +client_name: "dalpan robert"
    +created: "2021-09-09T15:18:56.000Z"
    +quantity: 16
    +organizer: "Virginie"
  }
  20 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4108
    +id: "4tsel0flajf8ta25jh7kn3gtev_20210930T100000Z"
    +client_name: "mosel"
    +created: "2021-04-23T09:35:45.000Z"
    +quantity: 15
    +organizer: "Sarah"
  }
  22 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4118
    +id: "3ktdbekj8ql9aao5o6o0f8avlq_20210920T060000Z"
    +client_name: "antonello di pinto"
    +created: "2021-04-23T08:49:09.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Sarah"
  }
  23 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4120
    +id: "7o85cboab4m6vg2sabklrns3oi_20210923T063000Z"
    +client_name: "konsbruck leon"
    +created: "2021-04-26T12:49:55.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "Sarah"
  }
  25 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4126
    +id: "11heho3r2a2v1g35e2b595c9bv_20210924T100000Z"
    +client_name: "ries beccy"
    +created: "2021-04-26T12:48:29.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Sarah"
  }
  26 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4146
    +id: "3j1v9tl8mfjtsc16q6nguk9ij4_20210930T063000Z"
    +client_name: "gillain rene"
    +created: "2021-04-23T09:37:30.000Z"
    +quantity: 9
    +organizer: "Sarah"
  }
  28 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4084
    +id: "56neogrn47h8ke9njq1eakol90_20210908T110000Z"
    +client_name: "boly marie"
    +created: "2021-04-28T14:03:45.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "Sarah"
  }
  29 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4141
    +id: "0l1o73ao4an2mkti32mme94bk9_20210906T103000Z"
    +client_name: "ozen yasin"
    +created: "2021-04-23T08:51:04.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Sarah"
  }
  30 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4166
    +id: "3u3lbe6ea5pvk410ur7u86p883_20210909T070000Z"
    +client_name: "senturk"
    +created: "2021-09-06T11:47:34.000Z"
    +quantity: 14
    +organizer: "BOCHRA"
  }
  32 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4089
    +id: "60rm6c9kckr34bb5coq6cb9k6lj62bb26hi68b9o6dhj8or56csj0p1h60_20210929T070000Z"
    +client_name: "gourdon"
    +created: "2021-03-21T13:47:09.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "PRISCILLA"
  }
  33 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4184
    +id: "2eq7ei7f6et389j1efu139ci88_20210923T073000Z"
    +client_name: "weimerskirch viviane"
    +created: "2021-05-28T09:21:09.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "PRISCILLA"
  }
  34 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4034
    +id: "7l771nf257gs3i1fm85m4fhfhm_20210927T070000Z"
    +client_name: "huet henx"
    +created: "2020-05-29T14:53:37.000Z"
    +quantity: 16
    +organizer: "PRISCILLA"
  }
  35 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4175
    +id: "3uhv76fffiujfoqjuema3uodbr_20210924T103000Z"
    +client_name: "theisen nadine"
    +created: "2020-06-17T17:23:33.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "PRISCILLA"
  }
  36 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4200
    +id: "7ai2i9vino66tpj7r4bnejannt_20210930T073000Z"
    +client_name: "reuter claude"
    +created: "2021-05-31T13:33:22.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "PRISCILLA"
  }
  39 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4208
    +id: "741ek8okob0kmdnubdhh4u2hmc_20210915T113000Z"
    +client_name: "paler mady"
    +created: "2020-05-29T12:39:00.000Z"
    +quantity: 16
    +organizer: "PRISCILLA"
  }
  40 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4204
    +id: "prh1o9f1h1es98cs8a9m1ij8qh_20210928T070000Z"
    +client_name: "dawans sandrine"
    +created: "2020-05-29T12:47:48.000Z"
    +quantity: 18
    +organizer: "PRISCILLA"
  }
  42 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4229
    +id: "2curpsp6p4bsngnh90omrhlbit"
    +client_name: "bettinelli david"
    +created: "2021-08-27T13:11:38.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "VERA"
  }
  43 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4232
    +id: "00rri05qllfltkuv3v1k4m9pa8"
    +client_name: "decouvette philippe"
    +created: "2021-09-03T09:37:01.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "LAOUARIA"
  }
  44 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4214
    +id: "tvd9hceeg1j1kd7u0pvak8cnt1_20210927T113000Z"
    +client_name: "miteva diana"
    +created: "2021-08-27T09:03:11.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "VERA"
  }
  45 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4137
    +id: "2kqstkdcf6hmg49cdlk7evluqk"
    +client_name: "schmit annette"
    +created: "2021-09-07T12:26:06.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "LAOUARIA"
  }
  46 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4187
    +id: "15436pcrdube66u1hcveqk6omg"
    +client_name: "logos it"
    +created: "2021-09-08T14:46:16.000Z"
    +quantity: 10.0
    +organizer: "LAOUARIA"
  }
  47 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4104
    +id: "1ppjvsg735c8l84b44aqlv2bth"
    +client_name: "lopes dasilva frederic"
    +created: "2021-09-09T09:24:52.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "LAOUARIA"
  }
  48 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4248
    +id: "1odk4lu5r5q1gtcq7i124ioe2o_20210928T113000Z"
    +client_name: "decembry fabienne"
    +created: "2021-09-03T08:58:55.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "LAOUARIA"
  }
  49 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4058
    +id: "q24vsi4miq5tr6m52n1ms8ajbe_20210928T080000Z"
    +client_name: "aeco"
    +created: "2020-05-15T15:15:15.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  50 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4238
    +id: "2k6tsukguk1oml5hlaalkdo830_20210927T110000Z"
    +client_name: "koch"
    +created: "2020-07-17T09:08:47.000Z"
    +quantity: 16
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  51 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#1516
    +id: "02lo6l45i4u8lhfsme8cqsqs00_20210930T060000Z"
    +client_name: "thoma"
    +created: "2020-06-11T13:27:02.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  54 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4249
    +id: "q6ot5lsda9e6k02jmr3folc3eg_20210923T110000Z"
    +client_name: "ralinger"
    +created: "2021-04-08T09:52:24.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  55 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#1592
    +id: "7opk9hfb4j135urjlslaserqeh"
    +client_name: "mertens julie"
    +created: "2021-06-24T10:33:45.000Z"
    +quantity: 25
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  57 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#1582
    +id: "7cu1qqinaemsv70ug925e98ph2"
    +client_name: "feuillette"
    +created: "2021-09-08T14:23:18.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  58 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4254
    +id: "0rdh3nd2sjp4de5gv9kil6qpbr"
    +client_name: "moret julie"
    +created: "2021-08-23T07:31:36.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  59 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#1576
    +id: "h2rkn1cboj7m6pc3ef8dp9v006_20210928T110000Z"
    +client_name: "elsen emmanuel"
    +created: "2020-08-24T08:01:17.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Julie"
  }
  60 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4173
    +id: "222ahsc9ahe4rcel3snau821vm_20210929T063000Z"
    +client_name: "vallado"
    +created: "2021-05-25T10:48:22.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "Sandrine"
  }
  61 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4075
    +id: "eoksfhhe0am9bjc0qh71ehhluj_20210930T070000Z"
    +client_name: "poli"
    +created: "2021-05-31T12:29:30.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "Sandrine"
  }
  62 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4056
    +id: "1k6klgnbneciv38i1b9pih53ce_20210927T070000Z"
    +client_name: "welter isabelle"
    +created: "2021-06-02T13:51:20.000Z"
    +quantity: 10
    +organizer: "Sandrine"
  }
  63 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4057
    +id: "flkb46e8f88be8cp257vc3u7cf_20210928T103000Z"
    +client_name: "ar promotion"
    +created: "2021-06-03T13:58:52.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "Sandrine"
  }
  64 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4068
    +id: "7mst86a583dlk77eshuaaq4b8e"
    +client_name: "rossignol"
    +created: "2021-09-09T12:29:14.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "Sandrine"
  }
  65 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4069
    +id: "61e81mt5kf2kdd7gij4n7ncr22_20210917T063000Z"
    +client_name: "nafziger"
    +created: "2020-07-22T12:20:58.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  66 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4035
    +id: "v93h9ok93l78g191rvss7a56jm_20210924T110000Z"
    +client_name: "nafziger fille"
    +created: "2020-07-22T12:21:12.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  67 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4049
    +id: "6qsnsoumikfeukdatmdnetjf13_20210927T101500Z"
    +client_name: "kailis"
    +created: "2021-02-24T10:18:55.000Z"
    +quantity: 31
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  68 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4061
    +id: "544g9e9pnhjesb1557mtvffl78_20210928T110000Z"
    +client_name: "annarita ritta"
    +created: "2021-03-12T14:25:19.000Z"
    +quantity: 16
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  69 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4045
    +id: "64eggb85tvi0lalonkic49qbcr_20210929T100000Z"
    +client_name: "pletschette alice"
    +created: "2020-07-22T12:05:06.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  70 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4099
    +id: "c9ijgcj6clhm4bb16dgjgb9kcpijeb9p6sp32bb268rjcdb565ijgopo68_20210930T063000Z"
    +client_name: "behm michele"
    +created: "2020-09-09T10:04:56.000Z"
    +quantity: 15
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  71 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4060
    +id: "2147hphqdsmub0hjuc1tihnri3_20210929T060000Z"
    +client_name: "jeitz dani"
    +created: "2021-04-09T08:42:10.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  72 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4096
    +id: "3lg0h3bl8vks70d2ujrsh7v6od"
    +client_name: "cipriani caroline"
    +created: "2021-08-26T11:23:51.000Z"
    +quantity: 16
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  73 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4103
    +id: "6rht60mrann050qd252stc5k0q_20210929T070000Z"
    +client_name: "collignon natalia"
    +created: "2021-09-03T07:27:44.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "LAURIE"
  }
  74 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4079
    +id: "4lpse7fdrtkofch02no3a6oaj5_20210924T060000Z"
    +client_name: "karier serge"
    +created: "2020-08-13T11:27:51.000Z"
    +quantity: 51
    +organizer: "CLAUDIA"
  }
  75 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4119
    +id: "l4p1ulif5u7al0420fo0mr5oen_20210927T060000Z"
    +client_name: "franco caroline"
    +created: "2020-08-13T11:29:13.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "CLAUDIA"
  }
  76 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4259
    +id: "r69eigu03plqs20n8nlo7n66eg_20210927T063000Z"
    +client_name: "bikor diane"
    +created: "2021-07-04T08:41:02.000Z"
    +quantity: 48
    +organizer: "CLAUDIA"
  }
  77 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4113
    +id: "5h1luf59g04kscv8e10h15f6sj_20210921T070000Z"
    +client_name: "chtourou ilhem"
    +created: "2021-06-10T10:01:54.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  78 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4152
    +id: "30vpcgk6rhmggv86d85266b2p0_20210924T070000Z"
    +client_name: "neu herve"
    +created: "2021-06-29T12:27:19.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  79 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4091
    +id: "v2k8jmk5qm1m1tdaufj4oggott_20210927T070000Z"
    +client_name: "pletschette fernande"
    +created: "2021-06-09T13:11:58.000Z"
    +quantity: 14.0
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  80 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4149
    +id: "k3207smsh4dmn2uojdft36nc1g_20210927T110000Z"
    +client_name: "pletschette leonie"
    +created: "2021-06-09T13:12:36.000Z"
    +quantity: 14.0
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  81 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4106
    +id: "4bm66hnras30ms6nmv31efaess"
    +client_name: "torres stefano"
    +created: "2021-08-27T13:05:06.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  82 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4062
    +id: "5k0077e3ef5dp3a5vbfdtsund3"
    +client_name: "binda daniela"
    +created: "2021-08-30T10:57:36.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  84 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4155
    +id: "0kb983h3f73vj1uros46epo8ji"
    +client_name: "rudbach rita"
    +created: "2021-09-03T08:52:15.000Z"
    +quantity: 4
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  85 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4169
    +id: "7l45qtmfkkdtvqbpne2pmht9m6"
    +client_name: "aquilano matteo"
    +created: "2021-09-10T08:04:39.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  86 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4164
    +id: "0f2s0fab6t6gau1lbbb7qpp9t2"
    +client_name: "delamo olga"
    +created: "2021-09-10T13:17:43.000Z"
    +quantity: 6
    +organizer: "FATIMA"
  }
  87 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#1585
    +id: "7j48gncr1jdaqgjk57b83i3722_20210930T070000Z"
    +client_name: "eiden martine"
    +created: "2020-05-29T14:07:48.000Z"
    +quantity: 30
    +organizer: "Nuran"
  }
  88 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4190
    +id: "nthvtchor1eu5cmpl9av1mn0go_20210924T060000Z"
    +client_name: "cavalieri romain"
    +created: "2020-04-27T13:27:46.000Z"
    +quantity: 24
    +organizer: "Nuran"
  }
  90 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4172
    +id: "3uu5s4f747q0hstuqvlpmgdvol_20210924T063000Z"
    +client_name: "thill"
    +created: "2021-04-09T08:51:57.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  91 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4165
    +id: "51q3811llvbjcngr9osajfsma1_20210930T063000Z"
    +client_name: "karlsson jaana"
    +created: "2021-06-02T09:04:52.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  92 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4196
    +id: "4qe87tmkqvjr2npjjvrihou0h7_20210929T110000Z"
    +client_name: "kohl romain"
    +created: "2021-08-16T07:48:06.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  93 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4186
    +id: "i4f48pm3g7nec8b7bt6j2fem3b_20210928T070000Z"
    +client_name: "baudhuin catherine"
    +created: "2021-04-09T09:11:22.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  95 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4206
    +id: "37gaecjplupq7bqim7p3ol34kn_20210930T110000Z"
    +client_name: "cambou stephane"
    +created: "2021-08-27T13:34:35.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  96 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4170
    +id: "6h8e013t73m314pf0ebggd0uk7_20210917T063000Z"
    +client_name: "flener emmanuel"
    +created: "2021-04-16T15:27:15.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  99 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4212
    +id: "41hs11h0njmr78aic152otf2qj"
    +client_name: "schroeder anouk"
    +created: "2021-09-03T08:09:46.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  100 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4216
    +id: "3hhue49dt649q741fst3uh7uig"
    +client_name: "stuart"
    +created: "2021-09-06T11:47:00.000Z"
    +quantity: 20
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  101 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4215
    +id: "7h1ri4l37fms06er9opkm422hk_20210910T110000Z"
    +client_name: "marques soleuvre"
    +created: "2021-04-19T11:22:32.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  102 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4199
    +id: "2kfog79ahe2g3hg8hq1jate8e4_20210915T063000Z"
    +client_name: "schalbar"
    +created: "2021-03-19T13:44:29.000Z"
    +quantity: 12
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
  103 => App\Services\EventsMerge {#4054
    +id: "0u9rc3egsob11n51ij5snahltf"
    +client_name: "schu anne marie"
    +created: "2021-09-03T08:10:42.000Z"
    +quantity: 8
    +organizer: "Andrea"
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example].  In your case i would add the out put as well so that we can see what you are getting vs what you would expect to be getting.

Comment: I added the output, but it's not always that because each time it has a missing one or more.

Comment: Your code looks like javascript to me why are you tagging this php and laravel?

Comment: I'm using that code in laravel project, I was trying to add the PHP code but the post would be too long, so I just tag it and if requested I'll send the PHP code.

Comment: If the code is to long then please debug this your self we need to see a [example] not your full project.

Comment: ok, I'll try to give a minimum code.